# Apache Basic Authentication using FilesMatch within DirectoryMatch

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'd like to limit access to some specific PDF files but am having a bit of trouble with my Apache configuration. I've got the FilesMatch directive to work as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
   AuthName "Permission Required"
   AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd"
   Require valid-user
   AuthType Basic
</FilesMatch>
```

Now I understand that I can't be more specific in just my .htaccess file, and so I'd have to use LocationMatch or DirectoryMatch in my config file. I've tried the following, but with no success:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/somedomain.com/httpdocs"
   ServerName somedomain.com:80
   ServerAlias somedomain.com
   <DirectoryMatch "^/uploads/(dir1|dir2)">
      <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
         AuthName "Permission Required"
         AuthUserFile "/var/www/somedomain.com/bin/.htpasswd"
         Require valid-user
         AuthType Basic
      </FilesMatch>
   </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

The actual files are located: http://www.somedomain.com/uploads/dir1/somefile.pdf

I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: you opened `FilesMatch` and didn't close it (this applies to `DirectoryMatch`).

Comment: Sorry, I copy/pasted from the wrong place - I did actually have the line un-commented (fixed in my code now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/somedomain.com/httpdocs"
   ServerName somedomain.com:80
   ServerAlias somedomain.com
   <DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/somedomain.com/httpdocs/uploads/(dir1|dir2)">
      <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
         AuthName "Permission Required"
         AuthUserFile "/var/www/somedomain.com/bin/.htpasswd"
         Require valid-user
         AuthType Basic
      </FilesMatch>
   </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

I found what's wrong. Sorry I didn't pay attention at first:).
Probelm is `DirectoryMatch` is EXACTLY like `Directory` but it takes regex as argument. So when your document root is `/var/www/somedomain.com/httpdocs`  then **uploads** directory  should be indicated like this

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/somedomain.com/httpdocs/uploads/(dir1|dir2)">
      #Somemthibg goes here :-D
 </DirectoryMatch>
```